# How to access to Laravel response

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, response

I use API for a credit card validator and I write at Controller:

```
dd($ChargeResponse);
```

and I got this data:

[image]

How to access this object?

I try:
`$ChargeResponse->_email` but dont work...

UPDATE:
CONTROLLER:

```
$CardTokenChargePayload->setEmail($request->email);
$CardTokenChargePayload->setAutoCapture('N');
$CardTokenChargePayload->setAutoCaptime('0');
$CardTokenChargePayload->setValue('10000');
$CardTokenChargePayload->setCurrency('usd');
$CardTokenChargePayload->setTrackId('Demo-0001');
$CardTokenChargePayload->setCardToken($data['cko-card-token']);
try {
    /** @var RequestModels\CardTokenChargeCreate $CardTokenChargePayload **/
    $ChargeResponse = $charge->chargeWithCardToken($CardTokenChargePayload);
    //$ChargeResponse = json_encode($ChargeResponse);
    return collect($ChargeResponse);

} catch (checkout\helpers\ApiHttpClientCustomException $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception Message: ',  $e->getErrorMessage(), "\n";
    echo 'Caught exception Error Code: ',  $e->getErrorCode(), "\n";
    echo 'Caught exception Event id: ',  $e->getEventId(), "\n";
    return response()->json(['code' => '2000', 'message' => $e->getErrorMessage()]);
}
```

Comment: or How to transform to an Laravel Eloquent object ?

Comment: Show your controller code

Comment: I post controller code ...

Comment: “How to access this object?” Where from?!

Comment: I need to access $ChargeResponse->email and similar but how ...

Comment: When I try     return response()->json($ChargeResponse->value);
 I got :    Undefined property: com\checkout\ApiServices\Charges\ResponseModels\Charge::$value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the "Object" is not really an object, is an Array. So you can call your prop like this:

`$ChargeResponse['_emai']`

But if you want to transform it and use Collections you can do:

`$ChargeResponse = collect($ChargeResponse);`

and then you can use

`$ChargeResponse->_email`

Comment: hm, no I got Fatal error: Cannot use object of type com\checkout\ApiServices\Charges\ResponseModels\Charge as array in C:\wamp\www\dine\app\Http\Controllers\CheckoutController.php on line 77

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($ChargeResponse) @AleksPer

Comment: @AleksPer the img is cut

Comment: That property is protected. You cant access a protected property without a getter.

Comment: You could update the `Charge.php` class and create a getter for that property

Comment: but please look at the bottom where I have public JSON:   public 'json' => string '{"id":"charge_test_BEFA099D640M74EA7902","liveMode":false,"created":"2018-01-16T17:07:39Z","value":10000,"currency":"USD","trackId":"Demo-0001","description":null,"email":"jamesi@londonsteakhousecompany.com","chargeMode":1,"transactionIndicator":1,"customerIp":null,"responseMessage":"Approved"," ... ... how to use that JSON - how to convert to eloquent object and use it ?

Comment: I try:   $aa = collect($ChargeResponse->json);
    return $aa->value; but wont work ... I got error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$value

Comment: @AleksPer You need to parse the string to json first. Try `$data = json_decode($ChargeResponse->json)` and then get you values like `$data->value`